# PHPExcel not calculating formulas

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula, phpexcel

So im kinda new to phpExcel and im making a sheet with data from a form(not done but will come) but i have a problem my formulas wont calculate i have tested preset formulas and import formulas from the code but none wont work all i get is 0 and protected mode and if i click editsheet and click on the cell where the formula is and hit enter it works and calculate it

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** PHPExcel */
include 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';



// Load file if it doesn't exists
if (file_exists('Exceltime.xlsx'))
{
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('Exceltime.xlsx');
}
else
{
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
}



$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('C4', '10:00')
        ->setCellValue('D4', '18:00')
        ->setCellValue('E4', '01:30')
        ->setCellValue('F4', '=(D4-C4-E4)');

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('C5', '10:00')
        ->setCellValue('D5', '18:00')
        ->setCellValue('E5', '01:30')
        ->setCellValue('F5', '=(D5-C5-E5)');




$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('TidsRapport Namn');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-              officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Tidsrapport Namn.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(TRUE);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

So all it should do is import work clock hours Start/end/break and then the formula is calculating how many hours/minutes you work

also if there is a better way or something i should do im free to try it :)

Comment: The problem is that these are simply strings: they have meaning to you as a human, but no special meaning to PHPExcel.... you need to store these as MS Excel serialized timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better answer is to actually use MS Excel date/time values rather than hoping that PHPExcel/MS Excel will guess that your string values like (`'10:00'`) are supposed to be times.

As per the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#setting-a-date-andor-time-value-in-a-cell)

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('C4', PHPExcel_Calculation_DateTime::TIMEVALUE('10:00'))
        ->setCellValue('D4', PHPExcel_Calculation_DateTime::TIMEVALUE('18:00'))
        ->setCellValue('E4', PHPExcel_Calculation_DateTime::TIMEVALUE('01:30'))
        ->setCellValue('F4', '=(D4-C4-E4)');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C4:E4')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('hh:mm');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F4')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('[hh]:mm');
```

Comment: Nice it works! but my question now is will this work with php form so instead of '10:00' will it be a  $C4 etc and import it from a form and also is there a simple way to make a loop on this or do i need to make like 30+ ish of this because this thing that i make is a month each sheet

Comment: Why do you think a string variable may work differently than a string literal? As long as the value that the variable contains is correctly formatted to look like a time value.... and PHP gives you all the tools to write loops, though you may be able to use the worksheet's `fromArray()` method